# Deep frying with tallow in a stainless steel pot

Tags: deep-frying, stainless-steel, beef-tallow

I do not have access to a cast iron pot, only a thin, lightweight stainless steel pot.

Will I be able to deep fry potato slices in beef tallow in it?

I am afraid the heat distribution will be uneven and that the tallow will catch fire even if I monitor the temperature (due to uneven temperature distribution)

Is there anything else I should think about or is it the same as fring in vegetable oil in a cast iron pot?

Comment: Safety - do you have a good-fitting lid for this pot, in case theres a need to smother it ?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you will have the risk of fire, as long as you keep the oil in the pot. Temperature will modulate more quickly than in cast iron, but it is not going to vary much within the pot itself.  I use a wok because the slanted sides make for safer deep-frying. So, you don't need cast iron.   In a pot, you need to be careful that when you add your ingredients, the oil does not boil over.  So, I would recommend filling less than 1/2 way, and using a thermometer to monitor the temperature.

Answer (score 7):

You can't really get uneven heat distribution in a pot full of liquid. The liquid on the bottom heats, causing it to expand and become lighter than the liquid above it. This leads to a constant convective circulation and even heat distribution, no matter how unevenly the heat is applied. Cast iron is not required here, nor even particularly helpful.

Comment: Cast iron does have one benefit in that it will hold on to more heat, giving you a smaller temperature drop when adding food to the oil.